# How to convert python3-pyqt code into .app file for mac os x?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

for python2.x py2app will do the work. But for python3 code which one is alternate to go ahead?

Or is there any other way to get single .app file?

Answer (score 0):

py2app claims to support Python 3, so you should be able to use it.